# Reordering an array so that far apart elements are ordered first

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have an array `A` of size `n`. I want to reorder the elements of `A` into another array `B` in such a way that elements that lie far apart in `A` are ordered first in `B`. For example, if `n = 9`, the two first elements of `B` should be `A[0]` and `A[8]`, since these are the two elements furthest apart in `A` (distance 8). `B[2]` should be `A[4]`, since that element is farthest from `A[0]` and `A[8]` (distance 4). Next we get `B[3] = A[2]` and `B[4] = A[6]`, since `A[2]` and `A[6]` are farthest from `A[0]`, `A[4]`, and `A[8]` (minimum distance 2). Finally `A[1], A[3], A[5], A[7]` in the last four positions of `B` (minimum distance 1 from the already added elements).

What is a fast algorithm for doing this, and handling arrays for arbitrary size `n`?

Comment: So you mean “distance” in terms of original array _index_ only, and not based on actual array element _values_? In that case, your requirement sounds to be close to how a binary search works, by recursively splitting the array into two equal halves …

Comment: That is correct. But a binary search only looks at one of the halves.

Comment: That’s why I said “close”, not “identical” … should be obvious that you keep working recursively with _both_ halves here instead of just one, until there is nothing more to split in half.

Comment: And what do you want to happen if the array has an _even_ number of elements? Insert both elements “below” and “above” the uneven middle of the current half array at the same time, or …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for any arbitrary size. It uses a breadth first search http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

```
static List<Integer> maxDistance(int _start, int _end) {
  List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(_start, _end - 1));
  List<List<Integer>> ranges = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(_start + 1, _end - 1));

  while(!ranges.isEmpty()) {
    List<List<Integer>> ranges2 = ranges;
    ranges = new ArrayList<>();
    for(List<Integer> range: ranges2) {
      int start = range.get(0),
          end = range.get(1);
      if(end - start == 1) {
        result.add(start);
      } else if(end > start) {
        int mid = (start + end)/2;
        result.add(mid);
        ranges.add(Arrays.asList(start, mid));
        ranges.add(Arrays.asList(mid + 1, end));
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:
You copy the first element.  Take the length of the array as a step size, and copy the odd multiples of this.  Halve the step size, then repeat until all the elements have been copied (and the step size is 1).
Implementing this in Java might look like this:

```
public static int[] farApartSort(int[] A) {

// Set up
int[] B = new int[A.length];
int i = 0;

// First value
B[i++] = A[0];

// Loop through the array in increments which halve each time
int chunkLength = A.length - 1;
do {
    // Take the odd multiples of the current increment
    for (int j = 1; chunkLength * j < A.length; j += 2) {
        // Copy the values into the sorted array
        B[i++] = A[chunkLength * j];
    }
    chunkLength /= 2;
} while (chunkLength > 0);

return B;
```

}

Comment: Your solution works for an array of length 9 and any other array length which is one larger than a power of 2 but fails for all other case. Try n = 32 for example. Then only 26 values will be written into B, the rest will be 0.